# ArcPy GridIndexFeature doesn't calculate square Grids - But using the tool in ArcGIS Pro desktop it does

Tags: arcpy, coordinate-system, arcgis-pro, grids-graticules, tools

I am currently trying to create Grids for several counties in my country.
Therefore I wrote a Python script using ArcPy and the GridIndexFeatures tool.

I want a 1000x1000 Meters Grid. If I am using the tool directly in ArcGIS Pro it works fine. If I run the Python code, I get a grid, that is 1000 Meters high but just 568 Meters wide. I don't know why, I use the exact same parameters in the tool and in the code.

I'll attach some screenshots.

Is this some coordinate system issue?

[image: 1000x1000x Meters grid created in ArcGIS Pro]

[image: 1000x1000x Meters grid created with python script]

[image: Tool in ArcGIS Pro]

[image: Arcpy function]

Comment: What is the coordinate system in the map canvas?  Some. like Web Mercator, are so wrong as to be useless for measurement.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I solved it. It was the wrong coordinate system, I think the tool within ArcGIS uses automatically the coordinate system of the map, which was UTM 32N, but arcpy uses the coordinate system of the input layer, which was Web Mercator. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: @SonofaBeach please add your solution as answer

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the same parameters in the Desktop application as in the arcpy script.

Re-run the script using the same parameters and see if you get the same results. Eg, your arcpy script does not include: number of rows, number of columns, etc.  This is a very complicated tool to get all the parameters right, because of the way that some parameters are ignored/used depending on how other parameters are set.

If you really want to compare them, then include ALL of the parameters in the arcpy command.

To see the exact set of parameters used by the desktop GUI took, check the tools log after running.

(Copied/pasted from comment as requested, then formatted a little better.)